# For loop with if statement is not sending the value to the text box

Tags: c#, arrays, if-statement, for-loop

I am comparing specific position [0] in array 1 with position[i] in array 2 and when they are equal to each other I want 3rd array with position[i] to be placed in textbox field.

Problem is that value wont be placed in the textbox.
I've checked if the values are equal and they are.

```
MessageBox.Show(" id [0] is : " + id[0] + "orderID [0] is : " + orderID[0] + " name 0 is : " + name[0]);
```

Message box shows:

[image]

Here is the for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < id.Length; i++)
{
    if (orderID[0] == id[i])
    {
        text1.Text = name[i];
    }

}
```

EDIT : 
Declaration :

```
string[] orderID = new string[aa.Length];
        string[] id = new string[bb.Length];
        string[] name = new string[bb.Length];
```

Comment: What you want, the MessageBox to print? What is wrong with the current op

Comment: Seems like that would be easier, less convoluted and less error prone with a `List<T>`

Comment: @un-lucky - I edited my post. I forgot to paste few lines.

Comment: so .. put a break point in the if statement and see if it hits ..

Comment: @Slai - Thank you for your suggestion, but I already tried that.

Comment: @un-lucky I'm really sorry, I've edited my post. I want the value to be placed in the text box.

Comment: please add the declaration for orderId and id array

Comment: are `orderID` and `id` string arrays?

Comment: @SirRufo MessageBox is outside of for loop and if statement. I'm using it just to check the position. If I manually set if statement to 0 position for every array, it also won't work, so I guess problem is with validation.

Comment: @Slai Yes they are.

Comment: then try `if (orderID[0].Trim() == id[i].Trim())`

Comment: @Slai  - Thank you very much sir! It worked like charm!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have new line characters `'\n'` in `id[0]` and `orderID[0]` because I don't see them in your code, but the MessageBox shows them.

When you fill the arrays, trim the strings or convert them like this :

```
orderID = orderID.Select(s => (s ?? "").Trim()).ToArray();
id = id.Select(s => (s ?? "").Trim()).ToArray();
```

Then you can simplify your code to

```
int i = id.IndexOf( orderID[0] );      // this returns -1 if not found
if ( i >= 0 ) text1.Text = name[i];
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but I get this error : [PrintScreen](http://prntscr.com/bsyxa0)

Comment: I didn't think it would be that bad .. then you can replace `s.Trim` with `(s ?? "").Trim`

Comment: It works for the  [1st part : ](http://prntscr.com/bt8ll7) 
  But not for the [2nd part :](http://prntscr.com/bt8lsh)
Code [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/bt8msm) because of the length.
 I am splitting file 1a.dll to 2 array strings. First one is with even position and second one is with odd.

Comment: Add the code to your question, and maybe sample of the 1a.dll file

Comment: Actually .. better just post it as a new questin